# vb.net Program not closing

Tags: vb.net, dispose, exit

So this is my code in a Function of a Module.  I'd like to close the program where I call `Application.Exit`, but it keeps running.  Is there a good reason for that?

```
  Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New FolderBrowserDialog
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        pictureFolder = OpenFileDialog1.SelectedPath

        movingPictures(pictureFolder)

        'GetImagePath()

    Else

        Dim answer As DialogResult
        answer = MessageBox.Show("The Program needs this folder to continue, " & vbCrLf & _
                                  "Choose Retry to try again, or Cancel to close.", "Retry or Close?", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        If answer = vbRetry Then
            GoTo RepickOpenfileDialog
        Else
            ' essentially ... here is where I'd like to close the program ... 
            ' but it simply won't... it keeps running though the code... 
            ' there a good reason for that ?
            Application.Exit()
            Form1.Close()
        End If
    End If
    processLock = 0
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code is actually following the path to the Application.Exit call?  Are you hitting the Application.Exit line when you step through with the debugger?  That would be the most obvious problem.

Comment: Yeah i walked though it , it keeps running my code - almost 200 lines of code before i'm like -.- and stop debugging

Comment: Why are you starting from a Module?  What happens in movingPictures()?  Do you have a **loop** in movingPictures?  How does the code you posted get triggered again?

Comment: Well it gets trigger with a function call from main, runs through all of it, gets to the application.exit() code, 

so the program hits the else part goes over application.exit, and continues on down the end if back to the function that called it, wich calls another function after this one

Comment: What is processLock?  Are there other thread being executed?

Comment: -.- ...... i have 5 threads 1 of them was not closed / set to nothing, sorry about that thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds like a really bad overall design.  For threads, you can set the IsBackground() property to True and it will be killed automatically when Application.Exit() is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is processLock? Are there other threads being executed?  If so this could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Exit method does not raise the Closed and Closing events, which are obsolete as of .NET Framework 2.0.

The Form.Closed and Form.Closing events are not raised when the Application.Exit method is called to exit your application. If you have validation code in either of these events that must be executed, you should call the Form.Close method for each open form individually before calling the Exit method.

Depending on what all is invoked try something like this...

```
If Not answer = vbRetry Then
        Form1.Close()
        Application.Exit()
    Else
        GoTo RepickOpenfileDialog
End If
```

Additionally, please verify your code is breaking on the Apllication.Exit() line. You may need to explicit close the modal dialog using the .close method...